# Automate Google chrome

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, automation, python-requests

I hope you are ok.
I'm trying to make a script open chrome for me and then click on a tap :

```
import os
import subprocess
import pyautogui
cmd = 'google-chrome'
if (subprocess.call(cmd)):
    pyautogui.click(618, 671)
#use it to know your screen position you may need to install scrot
# pyautogui.displayMousePosition()
```

but when I run the script I get an error, the error said :
[6869:6869:1111/121828.562003:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(374)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
[6815:6848:1111/121828.628223:ERROR:media_history_store.cc(363)] Failed to create or update the media history store.
**Any ideas about how I can solve it.**

Answer (score 1):

`subprocess.call(cmd)` is a blocking call and your program will not continue.

Use `subprocess.Popen(cmd)` instead

Anyways to overcome that error, you should change your command to `google-chrome --disable-gpu --disable-software-rasterizer`

and don't run in `sudo` :)

Comment: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'google-chrome --disable-gpu --disable-software-rasterizer'

Comment: please check the docs on how to use arguments properly https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor